# How data will flow through TCP/IP Stack

Tags: networking, tcp

An application using a TCP/IP stack has a 2500 bytes of data to send. It sends 
the entire data to the network stack. The underlying LAN used is Ethernet (802.3).
What happens to the data in this case? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The TCP will split the 2500 bytes and send only segments that fit in the MSS, thereby packets that fit in the MTU. So for example, it will send 2 segments, 1480 + 1020.

Comment: what would be the data behaviour at Ethernet layer?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean to say how data will be embedded into Ethernet layer?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar The network engine will add a header and a trailer, fill in the MAC addresses, set the underlying protocol type and send the frame on its way.